# Анимируются оба объекта Jquery

Tags: jquery

Привет всем. Проблема в следующем есть 2 блока с классом .image. В каждом .image есть img и p. 
при hover на img надвигается с низу p и создается эффект затемнения с текстом типа caption, но проблема в одновременно анимировании сразу двух .image. А нужно только тот на котором происходит событие hover. Побывал и find() и parent() ни чего не помогает если кто поможет буду очень благодарен. Спасибо.
код ниже

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
  $(".disc").fadeIn().animate({
     height:"+100%"
  });
}, function() {
  $(".disc").animate({
    height:"-100%"
  });
});
```

Comment: Желательно бы верстку и еще раз о том что вы хотите чтобы происходило

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, класс `.disc` принадлежит абзацу с текстовым описанием. Описанное вами поведение происходит, потому что в обработчике выполняется поиск не внутри активного блока (на который навели курсор), а по всему документу. Исправьте это:

```
$('.image').hover(function() {
  $('.disc', this).fadeIn().animate({
     height: '+100%'
  });
}, function() {
  $('.disc', this).animate({
    height: '-100%'
  });
});
```

Comment: Да там точнее был p.disc

Answer (score 1):

Попробую угадать без примера:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".disc").fadeIn().animate({
     height:"+100%"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".disc").animate({
    height:"-100%"
  });
});
```

Comment: Вы читер !:)

Comment: Спасибо понял в чем геморой был))))
Почему читер?